# RN Image resizeMode: 'contain' strange behaviour

Tags: image, react-native, resize, flexbox

I want to get header with picture and title in a row like this:
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKW0D.png)

with this code:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:'#ccf6c0', flexDirection:'column',}}>
      {/* ======================= HEADER ===================================*/}
      <View style={{flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor:'#d5d5f7'}}>
         <Image
           source={require('./images/logo.png')}
           style={{resizeMode: 'contain', flex: 1}}
         />
         <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor:'#f7d5d5'}}>
           <Text style={{fontSize: 17, fontWeight:'bold', marginLeft: 7}}>
             Title
           </Text>
         </View>
       </View>
</View>
```

But I get this output: [Wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySZjd.png)
- there is unnecessary space above and below the image.

What I'm missing here to get result desired?

My guess: image has original size of 360x180 (so by default it should be half width of the 768 simulator screen), but Android accepts it as mdpi image and upscales to xhdpi (x2 in both directions), and then uses this upscaled image to calculate container height. And only THEN resizeMode: 'contain' applies (inside new double-height container).
Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens is that the image is resized and contained inside of its original dimension, if you don't force those dimensions as Alex Green correctly says to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution which works in this case is to direct use Dimensions in order to calculate and hard set size for image frame before image will be resized:

```
...
import Image, Dimensions, StyleSheet from 'react-native';
...
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageBox: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: width/2.12,
    height: width/4.24,
  },
  })
...
<Image
   source={require('./images/image.png')}
   style={styles.imageBox}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may look like a broken api but this is how I solved it on my case:

```
<Image source={require('./images/logo.png')} 
       resizeMode='contain' 
       style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}}/>
```

width and height `null` looks odd but this way you get rid the static size and adapt the View's size.

Comment: you are awesome.
It works!
But why in a such a strange way?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work eventually((
If container height chages, i.e. if attached in the row View (right one in my case) height decreases to i.e. one line (less than image claculated height) - 'contain' doesn't keep image's height.
Result is here: 
<img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/k1tidh.png" border="0" alt="Wrong resize">

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the style from your `Image` component and add a view around it. Then use that view alongside the `resizeMode='contain'` prop in the Image component to decide the images' size.

e.g:

```
 <View style={{  height: 200, width: 200, justifyContent: 'center';}}>
     <Image image={source} resizeMode="contain" />
 </View>
```